# query documents that has an array of objects with all its array elements containing the key with value as null

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to get all the documents that has an array of objects with all its array elements containing the key with value as null

```
{  "_id" : ObjectId("5d769272db4f632399abbb14"),
   "used":true,
   "contacts":[
     {email:null, username:"john"},
     {email:"steve@gmail.com",username:"steve245"}
    ]
},
{  "_id" : ObjectId("5d769272db4f632399abbb14"),
   "used":false,
   "contacts":[
     {email:null, username:"paul"},
     {email:null, username:"retinza612"}
    ]
}
```

result to retrieved

```
{  "_id" : ObjectId("5d769272db4f632399abbb14"),
   "used":false,
   "contacts":[
     {email:null, username:"paul"},
     {email:null, username:"retinza612"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) query operator to find documents where "contacts doesn't follow ($not) the fact that at least one email is not null" :

```
db.collection.find({
  "contacts": {
    $not: {
      $elemMatch: {
        email: {
          $ne: null
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Will result as expected